# Can Google V8 engine run different Javascripts in different contexts in different threads simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, v8, embedded-v8

I plan to embed Google V8 in my C++ application, which is a multi-threading process. I need to run multiple Javascripts concurrently. Can I create multiple V8 contexts and run different Javascripts in different contexts simultaneously in different threads? Each context has no need to communicate with others. I just want no lock or wait for script concurrent executing. Thanks!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/oN_3tVBd3H4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the contexts are from different Isolates.

Each isolate can only be entered by one thread at a time and you need to use v8::Locker to lock the isolate to the particular thread.